# IIS curretly processed requests counter

Tags: iis, performance, monitoring, iis-10, performance-counters

I am experiencing issue with my application and suspect it might be because I am testing on client Windows/IIS which has 10 concurrent request limit. Is there a way to monitor the current value of currently processed requests? I mean ideally in performance monitor there would be a counter that would say how many requests are processed currently. Note that I am not looking for current queue length - that one I found and it is per site (or app pool). I am looking for IIS wide value.